# mongod command on linux(ubuntu) spits out random messages

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

**mongod command on linux(ubuntu) spits out random messages and mongo refuses to connect with 127.0.0.1:27017**

Message on terminal

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-20T22:33:58.002+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-20T22:33:58.005+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-20T22:33:58.005+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-20T22:33:58.005+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":17540,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"AmrutheshwarO"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-20T22:33:58.005+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-20T22:33:58.005+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-20T22:33:58.005+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-20T22:33:58.006+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-20T22:33:58.006+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-08-20T22:33:58.006+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

**while running mongo subsequently on terminal** (I run this command on a different terminal window)

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:362:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

**My mongodb version is**

````
db version v4.4.0
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.0",
    "gitVersion": "563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu2004",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please post the `mongod` command you had used with any arguments.

Comment: i had the same problem today i renamed the /var/lib/mongodb and reinstalled mongodb now it works again

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same problem. Deleting **/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock** should fix it.

You can see in the logs it fails to remove it:

```
{
  "t": {
    "$date": "2020-08-20T22:33:58.006+05:30"
  },
  "s": "E",
  "c": "NETWORK",
  "id": 23024,
  "ctx": "initandlisten",
  "msg": "Failed to unlink socket file",
  "attr": {
    "path": "/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock",
    "error": "Operation not permitted"
  }
}
```